# How to debug Facebook Credits API callback?

Tags: facebook-credits

I'm working on Facebook Credits API integration and still haven't found a solution of how to debug the Facebook Credits callback on localhost...

I will appreciate any idea of to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use your localhost since facebook's public servers must use HTTP(S) to transfer and receive data from you callback file. You must host this file on a public facing server.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a tool called **[localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/)**, it's an easy way to share localhost web servers to the rest of the world.

1. Install it using RubyGems by running:

   ```
   $ sudo gem install localtunnel
   ```
2. Run your local web server on any port! Let's say you're running Apache on port 8080.
3. Run localtunnel passing it the port to share

   ```
   $ localtunnel 8080
   ```

   **Note:** the first time you run localtunnel you have to point to a public SSH key.
   Check the [README](https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel#readme) if you need help.

   Here's an example:

   ```
   $ localtunnel -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 8080
   ```

   You should see something like this:

   ```
   Port 8080 is now publicly accessible from
   http://8bv2.localtunnel.com ...
   ```

**Note:** every time you stop your local web server you should run localtunnel again and update your Facebook app configuration.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful. I wonder, is there a way of requesting the "localtunned" generated url?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://www.twilio.com/engineering/2011/06/06/making-a-local-web-server-public-with-localtunnel

Comment: You can learn a lot from `LocalTunnel::Tunel` (https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel/blob/master/lib/localtunnel/tunnel.rb).

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I think you can `curl http://open.localtunnel.com/` than open the tunnel by yourself following http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html using parameters parsed from the response